# Execute a plugin function when a user profile is updated

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a Wordpress plugin with several functions in it. This plugin works as expected and all functions do their job. Now I need to call one of the plugin's functions when a user updates his profile.

I tried the following piece of code within my plugin, but it didn't work.

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'myfunction');
```

What is the best practice to use Wordpress hooks? How can I call the function from my plugin when a user profile is updated?

here the strucure of my little plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: myplugin
*/
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'myplugin' );

function myplugin() {
add_options_page( 'myplugin', 'myplugin', 'manage_options', 'myplugin_id', 'myplugin_options' );
}
function myplugin() {
if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
    wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
}
?>
<div class="wrap">
<?php    echo "<h2>" . 'Galette users sync' . "</h2>"; ?>

<form name="galette" method="post" action="<?php echo str_replace( '%7E', '~', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Mise à jour" />
</form>
<?php
function function1() {
    stuff
}
function function2() {
    stuff
}
function function3() {
    stuff
}
function function4() {
    stuff
}
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
       function4();
} 
echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

And I want to call function2() when a user update a profile

Any Help someone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have too hook into one or two hooks:

```
//is run when you edit YOUR profile, and save it
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'function2' );
//is run when you edit ANY OTHER profile and save it
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'function2' );
```

Read more about hooks here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Hooks

Comment: I think I must add this hook at the end of my plugin,right?

Comment: Anywhere. Just make sure the function exist.

Mostyle i do it add_action()
and then on the row after i add the function()

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong. I do it exactly like that. When a user updates his profile, run a function. And thats the code for it. 

You have to provide more info, but the answer to the question "how do i run a function when a user updates his information is the above one"

For instance: how do you know its not running?

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to blame you. I'm know it's not working because the fonction work when I call it in my plug-in option page . The function print some stuff at screen and modify a external database. But when I use the hook on profile update it doesn't write anything and doesn't write in dB. Like I said I've test before the profile_update hook and it doesn't work too. I'm doing wrong something but I don't see were...

Comment: Here is the last version of my plugin. When I call my fonction from the admin panel it work fine, but no action on profil update. http://codepad.org/2HvZHQAN Like you can see, It write in external db and write in ftp in an other server. I add 'profile update ' action in many place for be sure, but it's not very usefull...

Comment: Realy sorry, but your new link match with my script, I think you haven't save yours changes. Can you explain me what do you made for getting a working script?

Comment: Thks!! The script is loading!!! but it's launched on profil load not at profil save it seems. I explain: when I do a modification in the profil, I must save twice for having my db update. Is it normal?

Comment: That could be because your script you run in the hook take so long to finnish that the page loads before. Dont really know how to solve that. But please mark my answer as the correct one.